# What knot can I use to connect to an eye bolt without losing tension?

Tags: rope-knots

So I have a rope that goes through an eyebolt, like in the image. I pull from `B` so it's as tight as it can be. `B` is under the eyebolt.

What knot can I use with this rope so I don't lose any of the *tightness* after pulling it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: In view of your previous questions, is this rope made of steel?

Comment: Nope, it's regular rope.

Comment: To get the best knot, we need a lot more information. What are you tying B to? Is the system under load as you are tying the knot or can you prop up the item being hoisted while you tie the knot. What type of load are you looking at supporting and how disastrous would slippage (a little or a lot) be?

Answer (score 10):

100% [Trucker's hitch](http://survivalworld.com/knots/truckers-hitch.html#.WjwhMHlG0-U). It's the only knot I'd ever use in the situation you described:

`..so I don't lose any of the tightness after pulling it.`

*From the linked page, above. Emphasis mine.*

The **Trucker's Hitch** (also called the Lorry Knot) is a self binding knot. It's most common use is for tying loads to secure them to a fixed point. For example to secure a canoe to a car top, a tarp to a trailer, or any application where a very tight rope is needed. This knot has many advantages. It is non-jamming, can be tied anywhere in the standing part of a line, and even under the most severe tension, these knots remain easy to untie.

1) You must first tie a quick release loop above the tie-down point. To do this, create a small bight with the running end, leaving plenty of tag to work with.

[image]

2) When this is complete, pass the running end around or through the tie-down point then pass it through the quick release loop.

[image]

3) Pull down on the running end to tighten.

[image]

4) Secure the knot with two half-hitches.

[image]

5) Pull tight.

[image]

You can also find several videos on YouTube demonstrating how to tie the knot.

Learning this knot is a game-changer.

Comment: @rbhat: The slip knot in the [trucker's hitch acts as a makeshift pulley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trucker%27s_hitch#Mechanical_advantage_and_friction), giving your pulls a (theoretical) 3-to-1 mechanical advantage. Friction reduces the mechanical advantage somewhat.

Answer (score 5):

Use a Midshipman's hitch (also called Taut-Line Hitch)

This is typically used to secure an awning or tent line to a peg, and it is adjustable.

For your application, make the loop part large and loose.  Then pull on B, near the eyelet to tighten the load, then slide the knot down until everything is tight.

See:  http://www.animatedknots.com/midshipmans/index.php

[image: step by step knot instructions]

Comment: Nice Edit @jon !

Answer (score 0):

The first knot that comes to mind, for tying to a ring against a force you can pull by hand (i.e., able to hold a hitch as you put the knot together), is the bowline, followed by the sailor's knot,  or even two half-hitches, a figure-eight or an anchor-bend.  If it's holding a force you can't pull by hand, maybe the taut-line hitch, or the similar knot used by aviators to tether their wings to the ground.  There is also a "girth hitch" used by riggers, where the load may be suspended on both sides of the knot.

Some of it depends upon how often you need to untie it and how durable and reliable it must be while holding.

Comment: Agreed.  First knot that came to mind was a "round turn and two half-hitches".  Would just have to keep the line tight while making the round turn so it stays tight.

Comment: actually I think it would be pretty tough to tie a bowline and keep the line under tension.

Comment: @agentp Nope. I do it on a regular basis, often with gloves on. Run the loop through the ring, half-hitch on the running line, holding it while you pull the free end to "flip" the hitch into the running line, forming the "hole" in the bowline structure, with the free end coming through. Then complete the knot with the free end looped around the running line (still taut), and "back through the hole", pulling it tight.  If it takes more than ten seconds, you're doing it wrong.