# How to secure rope around an eye bolt?

Tags: railing, rope-knots

I built a tree house for my kids and I’m in the process of putting up the railings. I’ve installed the 4x4 posts And I plan to run a 2x4 on top of the posts, but for the middle and bottom rail I’m using 3/4” rope that will be secured to eye bolts set in the 4x4.

What I’m wondering is if anyone knows of a good diy method for securing rope to the eye bolts? Tying will be difficult because the rope is so think but could be done if I have no other options. In reality I’d like to get a rope clamp like the one pictured below for each tie but they go for about $10 a pop for the ones large enough to secure a 3/4 rope. Since I have about 25 points to secure I’d prefer to avoid dropping that kind of money.

Is anyone aware of any way to make my own rope clamps for cheaper using rubber coated wire or anything else? Is there a clever way to secure these ropes that I’m just not aware of?

$10 clamp:
[image]

Comment: I would use some sort of hitch knot. It would be hard to tie, but not impossible

Comment: So make the loops in the rope - no clamps to cut, and a lot smoother than knots. As to doing them up into wood, wind one in and count the turns, then pre-twist the other end in the reverse direction.

Comment: Could be useful, https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/129381/42053

Comment: Why such a thick rope?

Answer (score 3):

With wire rope one can weave a [flemish splice](http://www.johnhemsley.co.uk/flemish-splice/) like this:

[image: flemish splice]

I don't know whether that's possible with other (non-wire) kinds of rope though. Maybe an [eye splice](https://www.animatedknots.com/eye-splice-knot), then?

[image: eye splice]

Either of these could be finished by covering it with some heat-shrink tube.

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment making loops is possible and done it with ropes of 10mm diameter to 50mm diameter - the technique is the same.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, it's just been ages since I've done it and couldn't remember the name. They use it for mooring lines for cargo ships, no reason it couldn't be done in measly 3/4" rope.

Comment: Video!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uivsF61ytLQ

Answer (score 1):

Rope Clamp

[image]
[image]

https://www.eagleind.com/accessories/

https://www.grainger.com/search/material-handling/lifting-pulling-positioning/wire-rope-and-fittings/wire-rope-clips?ts_optout=true&searchQuery=rope+clamp&categoryIndex=1

Please make sure you get/ask the maximum grip capacity and set a safety factor of 2 to 4. **Safe working load = Capacity/Safety Factor**.

Comment: Kids could get hurt from those thread ends etc...

Comment: Good point. Wrap the metal parts in plastic tape after connecting. There are plastic clamps that I wouldn't trust so didn't bother mentioning them. But I like the one brought up by @Greg Hill.

Comment: Acorn nuts would last far longer than some tape to cover the ends. That or cut off the end of the bolts just beyond the end of the nuts.

Comment: @FreeMan  That would be good excuse to have to buy a angle grinder, protect the kids.

Comment: Yay toys! err... tools!! (except I've already got 2 angle grinders...)

Comment: @FreeMan but now you need a cordless one :) to join the 4” and 6”…

Comment: Well, @SolarMike, they're both cordless 4.5"... :)

Answer (score 0):

I’d drill a hole in the post, pass the rope through it, and tie an [overhand knot](https://www.animatedknots.com/overhand-knot).